# Enhance assets:precompile on Heroku to add non fingerptinted filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In a Rails 4 app, I want precompiled assets to have copies of some assets to be available with a non fingerprinted filename. The app is deployed on Heroku.

I have the following rake task in place:

```
namespace :app do 
  task :nonfingerprint_assets => :environment do 

    manifests = Rails.application.config.assets[:precompile]
    manifests = manifests.slice(1, manifests.length)

    assets = Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/**/*'))
    regex = /(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}*\.{1}){1}/
    assets.each do |file|
      next if File.directory?(file) || file !~ regex

      source = file.split('/')
      source.push(source.pop.gsub(regex, '.'))

      non_digested = File.join(source)

      if manifests.any? {|m| 
        if m.is_a? Regexp
          m.match non_digested
        else 
          m.ends_with?(non_digested) 
        end
      }
        puts "** copy source:      #{file}" 
        puts "** copy destination: #{non_digested}" 
        FileUtils.cp(file, non_digested) 
      end

    end
  end
end

Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].enhance do 
  puts "Invoke nonfingerprint_assets"
  Rake::Task['app:nonfingerprint_assets'].invoke 
end
```

This rake task is working fine on my local machine even in production environment. It creates a file in `public/assets/application.js` which is the copy of the same file with a digest in its name.

When I deploy this code to heroku I get the following error message which I don't understand:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_
locales = false to avoid this message.
       Invoke nonfingerprint_assets
       ** copy source:      /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/public/assets/application-51d1660b66655782ab137ee98c789fdd.js
       ** copy destination: /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/public/assets/application.js
       rake aborted!
       No such file or directory - /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/public/assets/application.js
       /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/lib/tasks/production.rake:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/lib/tasks/production.rake:9:in `each'
       /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/lib/tasks/production.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_48b86bff-83f9-4d21-8b21-712c1baef811/lib/tasks/production.rake:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => app:nonfingerprint_assets
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Please help me to understand what's going on.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'd suggest you fix the areas of your site that are not using fingerprinted assets.

Comment: @Derek I want an external site to be able to reference some of my javascript assets. It's a third party javascript. I need a URL that does not change at each deploy.

Comment: Although I don't know the specific answer, you'd want to check out something like [Cloudfront](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn)

This will hold & serve your assets as-and-when required. You'll still have the problem of having to save / deploy your assets without fingerprinting though :/